# XMl string not being Validated with XSD

Tags: xml, vb.net, string, validation, xsd

I Have a valid XSD and the xml string with the different schema.
If I take the xml string and try validating with xsd schema through `xmldocument.validate`, it does not validate.

```
dim tmpdoc as new xmldocument()    
dim abc as string= file.readalltext("books-debug.xml")
tmpdoc.schemas.add(nothing,"New.xsd")
Dim eventHandler As New ValidationEventHandler(AddressOf ValidationEventHandler)

    tmpDoc.Validate(eventHandler)

End Sub


Private Shared Sub ValidationEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As    ValidationEventArgs)
    Select Case e.Severity
        Case XmlSeverityType.[Error]
            MessageBox.Show("Error: {0}" + e.Message)
            Exit Select
        Case XmlSeverityType.Warning
            MessageBox.Show("Warning {0}" + e.Message)
            Exit Select
    End Select

End Sub
```

xml used for the testing `books-debug.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<bookstore xmlns="http://myspace">
    <debugparameters>
        <parameter>
            <paramname>paramname1</paramname> 
            <description>description1</description> 
            <subsystems>
                <subsystem-id>g</subsystem-id> 
                <subsystem-id>f</subsystem-id> 
                <subsystem-id>d</subsystem-id> 
            </subsystems>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <paramname>paramname2</paramname> 
            <description>description2</description> 
            <subsystems>
                <subsystem-id>f</subsystem-id> 
                <subsystem-id>g</subsystem-id> 
                <subsystem-id>d</subsystem-id> 
            </subsystems>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <paramname>paramname3</paramname> 
            <description>description3</description> 
            <subsystems>
                <subsystem-id>f</subsystem-id> 
                <subsystem-id>g</subsystem-id> 
                <subsystem-id>d</subsystem-id> 
            </subsystems>
        </parameter>
    </debugparameters>
</bookstore>
```

xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"    targetNamespace="http://www.contoso.com/books" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="bookstore">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="book">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="writer">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="first-name" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="last-name" type="xs:string" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="genre" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="publicationdate" type="xs:date" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="ISBN" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Your XML has only one element in common with your XML. Are you sure that's the right instance or schema? Also the namespaces are completely different.

Comment: See if the schema below fixes your problem. If not, edit your question with it (since the one you posted is incompatible).

Comment: thank you for reply...my question is why am i not getting the any error even though the schema is different from xml

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but it won't fit in the comments, and it might be useful. Your schema is completely incompatible with your instance. I suggest you use the schema below (which validates your instance) as a starting point and see if it works with your system. If you still have problems you can delete this question and write a new one, or edit your question with the compatible schema.

Your schema is invalid. This one validates the instance you posted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"    
    targetNamespace="http://www.contoso.com/books" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="bookstore">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="debugparameters">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="parameter" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="paramname" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="subsystems">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="subsystem-id" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string" />
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

It can be associated with the instance like this:

```
<bookstore xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.contoso.com/books four.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.contoso.com/books">
    <debugparameters>
        <parameter>
    ...
</bookstore>
```

Note the namespace which is the same as the `targetNamespace` in the schema. One of the reasons your example wouldn't work even if it had all the correct elements declared is that the namespace didn't match.

Comment: thank you for reply...my question is why am i not getting the any error even though the schema is different from xml

Comment: In that case, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771874/how-do-i-validate-a-string-of-xml-against-an-xml-schema-file